# Why is STM32CubeIDE not showing SFR registers when debugging?

Tags: debugging, embedded, stm32

I imported a project in STM32CubeIDE with the option "Makefile Project with Existing Code". I created this project without using any IDE, so I had to write my own makefile.

```
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc -c
LD = arm-none-eabi-gcc

LIBNAME_OPENCM3 = opencm3_stm32f1

OPT = -Os
DEFS += -DSTM32F1
DIR_OPENCM3 = ./libopencm3
DIR_INC = ./inc
DIR_OBJ = ./obj
DEBUG = -ggdb3
LDSCRIPT = stm32f1.ld

DIR_FLAGS = -I$(DIR_INC)

ARCH_FLAGS = -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3

LDFLAGS += --static -nostartfiles
LDFLAGS += -T$(LDSCRIPT)
LDFLAGS += $(ARCH_FLAGS) $(DEBUG)
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-Map=$(*).map -Wl,--cref
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
ifeq ($(V),99)
LDFLAGS     += -Wl,--print-gc-sections
endif
LDFLAGS += -u _printf_float
LDFLAGS += -L$(DIR_OPENCM3)/lib

LDLIBS += -l$(LIBNAME_OPENCM3)
LDLIBS += -Wl,--start-group -lc -lgcc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group

CFLAGS += $(OPT) $(DEBUG) $(ARCH_FLAGS)
CFLAGS += -Wextra -Wshadow -Wimplicit-function-declaration
CFLAGS += -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS += -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
CFLAGS += -std=c11

DEFS += -I$(DIR_OPENCM3)/include

PREPFLAGS = -MD -Wall -Wundef $(DEFS)

OBJS = $(DIR_OBJ)/main.o \
        $(DIR_OBJ)/bmp180.o

main.elf : $(OBJS) $(LDSCRIPT)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS) -o main.elf
$(DIR_OBJ)/%.o : %.c
    mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DIR_FLAGS) $(PREPFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean :
    rm -rf $(DIR_OBJ) *.elf *.map *.d
all :
    make
```

The project is compiled successfully and it's running, but when I started to debug, this IDE didn't show the SFR registers. That window is empty.[image]

I created a different project, this time with the IDE, and it shows me the registers.
[image]

I suppose that it has something to do with my makefile. Is there an extra flag that I need to add or why is this happenning?

Comment: there is option to select target file for debugging register. You could open project configuration/debug configuration to compare. I got this issue long time ago and don't really remember exactly

Answer (score 1):

coming up on this after some time since i JUST faced the exact same problem (using STM32CubeIDE 1.9.0 on Win10)

It all generated when I imported an existing makefile project into the IDE...
Was able to debug from within the IDE (using STLINK) but SFR view was oddly empty...

I resolved by playing with the "Project Nature" settings, despite the threatening messages from the IDE itself ( too bad :S )

- after the import, the project got configured with 3 natures: ccnature, managedBuildNature, ScannerConfigNature
- I added a 4th nature: MCUProjectNature (select STM32CubeIDE Project from the list in the dialog which shows up)

ta-da!!!

The project Properties (finally!) started to show the CMSIS-SVD settings tab which allows me to point to the .SVD device file describing the MCU used

I specified this string (copied from a project generate completely inside the IDE):

platform:/plugin/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.productdb.debug/resources/cmsis/STMicroelectronics_CMSIS_SVD/STM32xxxx.svd

(replace xxxx with your MCU micro, search your STM32CubeIDE installation plugin folder for *.svd)

I hope this can relief the pain from banging one's head against the wall in search for a fix

Comment: I think I found a safer way to fix that: select your project, Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->MCU Settings. When I did that the box was empty, but I selected my MCU and it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case the drop down combo box where you select chip model only had one entry '0' without any detail. That didn't work, so the only way left was to play with project nature...